# Spring MVC: Obfuscating password in xml configuration file

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, encryption

I want to obfuscate, protect or encrypt the BD password in my XML configuration file. Is there any way to do that?

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myApp" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="p@ssw0rd" /> -- This is the one I want to encrypt.
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't have your credentials in that file, they should be provided as environment variables

Comment: System enviroment variables o Spring enviroment variables?

Comment: System environment is normally used for this -- usually specified inline before the call to 'java', rather than actually being set anywhere

Comment: Thanks @EngineerDollery!! I just found an article which explain all what you mentioned. http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring

Comment: Our daily "where do i store the db connection password" question. Try the search box